# getting multiple countdown timers from querysets using django models and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I really don't know how to push on with this, the idea is an investment platform where the user can have multiple investments and each investment has a due date [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGqIG.png)

this image shows that when I try to query the countdown timer it just shows for the first query set and it picks the new query added to the model query set

```
<script>

let timer =  new Date({{amt.timer|date:'U'}}*1000)
time = new Date(timer).getTime()
newbox = document.getElementById('box')

var interval =  setInterval(() => {                                    
  const now = new Date().getTime()
  const diff = time - now
  console.log(` this is testing diff ${diff}`)
  console.log(` this is testing ooo ${time}`)
  console.log(` this is testing now ${now}`)
  const d = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) )
  const h = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 
  60));
  const m = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const s = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  newbox.innerHTML = `${d} days ${h} hours ${m} minutes ${s} seconds`
  if (diff < 0) {
     clearInterval(interval)
   }
 {#console.log(time)#}
 {#console.log(diff)#}
 {#console.log('hello')#}

}, 1000)
</script>
```

this code is in the forloop. thanks, I hope I tried explaining the situation